# "rake aborted! Failed to connect to a master node" when running bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm having some problems with running `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.
The terminal prints out the following:

```
    [RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it.
rake aborted!
Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:9100
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:420:in `connect'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:594:in `setup'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:130:in `initialize'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:79:in `new'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:79:in `connect'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/connection.rb:89:in `setup'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo_mapper-0.12.0/lib/mongo_mapper/railtie.rb:28:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/User/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/Users/User.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/Users/User/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Just to clarify: before running bundle exec rake db:migrate I did bundle install and everything was OK. 
Anyone?

Comment: Is your database up and running? I know 9100 tends to be a port for Hadoop.

Comment: Update your config/database.yml file to point to the right db and like Devin said make sure the db server is running, stacktrace says it is mongodb

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I've installed and configured (with a test) MongoDB exactly as in this outline: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/.

When I type "rails s", it says that
/Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo-1.6.4/lib/mongo/connection.rb:420:in `connect': Failed to connect to a master node at 127.0.0.1:9100 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)

Comment: +When I type mongod, it says:
"all output going to: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"

Comment: I just found out that running "bundle exec rake db:migrate" with "RAILS_ENV="production" produces "[RailsAdmin] RailsAdmin initialization disabled by default. Pass SKIP_RAILS_ADMIN_INITIALIZER=false if you need it." followed by a list of migrations (users, tables, posts, etc.)

Comment: Update: My config/mongo.yml file looks like this:
__defaults: &defaults
  host: 127.0.0.1
  port: 9100

development:
  <<: *defaults
  database: app_development

test:
  <<: *defaults
  database: app_test

production:
  host: ...a.mongolab...
  port: ...5...
  database: ..._app...
  username: ..._app...
  password: ...19g....__
I personally think the issue lies in the _defaults_ section and something is wrong with the host/port numbers. I tried switching the port from 9100 to 27017, no change. The weirdest part is that when I actually run mongod, the testing page on the localhost loads all OK.

Answer (score 0):

Is your database running? This error message shows that it can't connect to your database.

Comment: This should be a comment on the question, not an answer.